# MapStruct doesn't always automatically map args with the same name

Tags: kotlin, mapstruct

I have the mapper below;

```kotlin
@Mapper
abstract class CategoryMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "includeInAppList", constant = "true")
    @Mapping(target = "categoryName", source = "categoryId", qualifiedByName = ["categoryName"])
    abstract fun newCategory(categoryId: String): LocalCategory

    fun newCategory(categoryId: Set<String>): List<LocalCategory> =
        categoryId.map { newCategory(it) }

    @Named("categoryName")
    open fun categoryName(input: String): String {
        return input.lowercase().replaceFirstChar { it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) }
    }

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE: CategoryMapper =
            Mappers.getMapper(CategoryMapper::class.java)
    }
}
```

This generates the code below;

```java
public class CategoryMapperImpl extends CategoryMapper {

    @Override
    public LocalCategory newCategory(String categoryId) {
        if ( categoryId == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        String categoryName = null;

        categoryName = categoryName( categoryId );

        boolean includeInAppList = true;
        String categoryId1 = null;

        LocalCategory localCategory = new LocalCategory( categoryId1, categoryName, includeInAppList );

        return localCategory;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the generated code creates and then use the `categoryId1` variable. I can fix it quite easily by adding `@Mapping(target = "categoryId", source = "categoryId")` to my mapper class but I feel that defies the whole point of using MapStruct for this kind of thing.

Comment: I can't explain why this isn't working. Maybe it is some kind of a bug, I would suggest trying it without Kotlin and / or create a bug report (https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues) so that we can look into it